# How to assign an array to data of charts.js's counts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I have a `chart.js` graph, I want to assign an `array` on `data`

This is my current code

```
datasets: [
    {
      data:[40,56,345,2354],
      backgroundColor: "#007BA7",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#00CC99"
    }
]
```

But I want to use `array` which has `list` of `products`. This is how I am doing but it is not working

```
datasets: [
    {
      data: this.lastSeenDeviceCount.forEach(element => {
        element.length
      }),
      backgroundColor: "#007BA7",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#00CC99"
    }
]
```

This is datasource information

```
this.lastSeenDeviceCount.push(activeRecords,offlineRecords, pendingRecords);
//array has this object
{
    "DeviceID": "52",
    "FriendlyName": "Net RC",
    "UserName": "UserNet",
    "LastSeen": "07/23/2020 23:18:05",
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this ?
`this.lastSeenDeviceCount.map(element => element.length)`
Actually I could'nt figured out what your intention of returning `element.length`

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU - Its working. You can write your comment as answer as you was the first to answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ? `this.lastSeenDeviceCount.map(element => element.length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this;

```
let devices = []; // array to store all devices
this.lastSeenDeviceCount.forEach(element => {
  devices.push(element.length)
})

datasets: [
  {
    data: devices,
    backgroundColor: "#007BA7",
    hoverBackgroundColor: "#00CC99"
  }
]
```

What's happening here is that;

1. You created an array
2. You populated the array from the loop logic
3. Then you pass the value of the array to the chartJs **data** property to populate the chart

Comment: I was doing like this but to use records, Then I need another array of type actual records.